# Windows 7 is very slow to open files on another Windows 7 share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I have two machines running Windows 7 Enterprise, one of which has a shared folder. I open it on startup using a batch file that contains the following command:

```
net use \\myip\share /user:username password
```

Everything is fine and I can browse the share quickly; everybody is happy.

However when I open an XLS file in the shared folder on the remote computer, it takes a couple of minutes to open - meanwhile the green progress bar on the window's path location slowly fills up.

How can I speed up the process?

No strange antivirus or other software are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this issue isolated to the excel file.... how about similarly sized files?

Browsing is not network intensive like opening a file. The speed of your network is probably a lot slower than you thought it was.  Fixing the root cause of the network slowdown will remedy the situation if it is persistent for all browsing.

We need more information:

1. Only with excel files / or this single file
2. Network infrastructure
3. How about copying the file from the network share to the local drive, is that faster?

Comment: 1. I'll test and get back
2. Silly workgroup static ip based
3. Definitely: works without problems

Comment: The issue was isolated to a single excel file's: permission problem.
Very strange indeed since the user we're talking about was admin :/
Everything is fine now: I've copied the file and deleted the old one.